# Can I write Java code in XCode 3.2.1?

Tags: java, xcode

I would like to know is there any way to program (write, compile and execute) Java in XCode as I don't see any Java templates. Does that mean that it's not possible?

Answer (score 15):

Click Choose Window > Organizer to open the Organizer. Then click + at the bottom of the Organizer. Choose New From Template > Java Templates.

Anyway, I personally feel better with [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org) for Java development.

Comment: Though I'll definitely give a try at XCode to figure out whether it can debug from Java to C in my projects involving JNI

Answer (score 3):

Do you really want to? I recommend checking out any of the really good and free Java IDEs; IntelliJ IDEA CE, Eclipse, or NetBeans.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) or [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), but the [Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/) [design tool](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XCodeDesignTools/Introduction/Introduction.html) is delightful. The "Quick Model" feature is specially handy for visualizing an existing class library. Choosing `New File` from the `File` menu should show Java templates, and you'll find example projects in `/Developer/Examples/Java/`.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK no, you should really use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) for Java development on the OS X Platform.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans is a really good IDE nowadays. I've been using it from version 3.6 and it has had a huge improvement phase until current Netbeans 6.9.1
Good support for third party frameworks like Spring and of course the best support for Swing applications (desktop applications)

Answer (score -1):

Eclipse is horrible. Complex, slow, hard to use, makes simple tasks complicated.  If you have to use an IDE, use Xcode.  Otherwise, I find a text editor and Make to be much cleaner and easier.

Comment: So your answer to "Can I code Java in Xcode?" is "use Xcode, not Eclipse"? Keep in mind that this is not a forum. If you meant this to be a comment on another answer, don't post it as an answer.