# Java programming on a Mac?

Tags: java, macos, ide

This may be a really stupid question, but I cannot find anything anywhere as all of my searches provide the wrong results.

I am looking for a Java development program on the Mac, think of Visual Studio.NET for Windows. Is there anything that I can get, and where?

I have looked on the Java website but I don't know which download I will need. If anyone can help, that'd be much appreciated!

Comment: You used Visual Studio.NET for Java programming on Windows? That's…uncommon.

Comment: Google: "_osx java ide_", second and third hit are NetBeans.org and Eclipse.org

Comment: @Chuck, no, I used it to code Visual Basic, but the fact that it was a design environment was the point I was trying to get across.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both http://netbeans.org/ and http://www.eclipse.org/ work on a Mac

Answer (score 6):

Eclipse or NetBeans is what you are going to want.  They will have the most similar feel to VS.

Answer (score 4):

[Eclipse for mac](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.7-201106131736/eclipse-SDK-3.7-macosx-cocoa.tar.gz)

Answer (score 3):

There are some good [integrated development environments (IDE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) for java, which also work on Mac OSx. Which is the best, depends a little bit on you.

Here a short list:

- [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) - I think one of the most popular development environments for java and some other languages.
- [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) - not free for commercial development, but I really like it
- [Netbeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/) - the most "official" one.. In 2005 all SUN IDE products were integrated into netbeans. In netbeans is a good [graphical build tool (Matisse)](http://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html) for Swing user interfaces included, which is nice for some prototyping or fast development and maybe more.
- [Eclim](http://eclim.org/) - If you adore vim, this could be interesting for you. It's a mixture of eclipse and vim.

Answer (score 1):

[Xcode Developer Tools](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/) may already be installed on your system in `/Developer`.

Comment: I occasionally use Xcode 3.1.4; can't say about later versions. I prefer NetBeans & Eclipse, which are _much_ more powerful. The examples are in `/Developer`.

Comment: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963226/can-i-write-java-code-in-xcode-3-2-1/1963278#1963278).

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is the best option for Java development in a Mac, I'm using that for 3 years for develop J2EE, Java Swing and Android applications.