# Writing a Java program in Xcode

Tags: java, xcode

I am trying to begin writing a Java program in `Xcode 4.4` but, At the moment, I am stuck with the file extension `.cpp`, which I believe is for C++. Can some please tell me how to set up a `.java` file (or project, or whatever the term is)...? I am extremely new to programming, and to Xcode, so please keep all instructions /very/ simple.

Comment: it's doable but your better off with netbeans or similar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963226/can-i-write-java-code-in-xcode-3-2-1

Comment: Real programmers use notepad:P

Comment: +1. Especially, if you are new to java. You should go with plain editor+shell.

Comment: See the examples in `/Developer/Examples/Java/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created some Xcode Templates for Xcode 4 here
http://www.2shared.com/file/hExLjJ1X/Java_Xcode4_template2.html

To install the template in Mac, use Terminal command

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/
unzip ~/Downloads/Java_Xcode4_template2.zip -d ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/
```

You can use command-B to build.  To Run, you should use "Edit Scheme..." and change the Executable for the "Run" Scheme

Comment: Are a able to share the template on a site that doesn't require a registration? A github repo?

Answer (score 2):

If you're new to programming you might want to try this in a different way.

Better IDEs for Java are Netbeans and Eclipse.  I've used Netbeans for Java and PHP as well.  It behaves as you could expect from a modern IDE with a lot of possibilities for customizing it to your needs/preferences.

Xcode is great and has many useful tools but it's focused on objective-c and iOS environment.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am using XCode currently.

1. Open a new project.
2. Click External Build System.
3. Name your file, using the extension .java.
4. Write $(TARGETNAME).java next to $(ACTION).
5. Open a new file (empty style).
6. Start writing your program.

XCode is not the best place for Java, but I use it since it is a developer tool for Apple and it has great syntax coloring and auto-indentation, etc.

TextEdit is another app (probably already there if you use Apple Mac), but no syntax coloring and fancy features. It is simpler to use, and always use Terminal (try to avoid using the XCode Build - the errors are hard to decipher and the process is complicated, also if you have any questions, few can answer it because most do not use XCode).

Good luck!